# Asking for moderator to see my deleted questions

Tags: support, deleted-questions, moderators

I have deleted some of my bad questions in the past, and I am seeking for a way to undelete them and make them better so I can have my ban lifted.

I heard that in order to do that, I should find a moderator. How to I find one?

Comment: Well, they usually have diamonds next to their names.

Comment: Oh thank you, i did not know that

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators

Comment: You can flag one of your existing posts and ask a moderator to undelete questions for you.

Answer (score 8):

Your deleted questions:

- [Making Program extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415620/making-program-extensions)
- [Selling play store apps from non-checkout countries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595616/selling-play-store-apps-from-non-checkout-countries)
- [Simultaneous TCP Send/receive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244844/tcp-simultaneous-send-recieve)